# Why does nested display:grid kill performance (but flex does not)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I have a relatively simple layout situation that seems to drastically lose performance when using `display: grid`.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-albattani-3gnx6

I have a header and a child container, which will recursively render the main component if the option is checked. Performance dips around depth=7, and will be essentially unusable by depth=10. More complex examples will fail much earlier.

What I'm having trouble understanding is why changing

```css
display: grid;
```

to

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

has absolutely no issue, even up to depth=50+. I've tried changing grid parameters to behave just like flex would, without any difference. I would imagine that the layout logic behind the scenes for the two would be near identical for this case?

I'm using modern hardware, and tested in chrome-89, firefox-86.

Comment: why do you need so many nested grids?

Comment: @evolutionxbox In a non-minimal example, with styling and content in the header/child, performance will drop as early as depth=4, which I don't believe is too excessive. Flex still maintains perfect performance though.

Comment: Well, `flex` is an older (and well optimized) tool, much older than `grid`, since `grid` was released it had a bad reputation about performance when compared to `flex`. As you can see, we still facing that problem nowadays.

Comment: @Leo wasn't grid released in 2015? I think fundamentally grid is significantly more complex than flexbox. flex is 1D, grid is 2D

Comment: @evolutionxbox even earlier, but updated (as it is today) in ~2017, flex made it around ~2012. I understand you, dates doesn't matter that much, the fact is that we are saying the same thing: grid is newer, optimization is lower, and computation is much higher.

Comment: Just to share my experience: I built a calendar using grid. Each day can contain an indefinite number of items. The items needing some slightly elaborate layout, I went with grid too, even though I'm more familiar with flex. Lots of grids within a grid: on scroll, painful repaints like I've never seen. (At least, I think I know the solution.)